# Move sendmail from Fedora 1 to a different server ( fedora 12)

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dhcp, sendmail

We have a sendmail server that also works as DHCP, DNS, and a gateway to our ISP. It has three network interfaces, one for our ISP ( static IP)  and the other two is for LANS on different subnet. The hardware is quite old and we've been experiencing downtime due to hardware failures, so we have decided to upgrade the hardware and while at it upgrade the linux OS to Fedora 12. Were trying to do this with minimal downtime.

We are planning to take these steps.

1. Install New OS (Fedora 12) on the new server with 3 network interfaces.
2. Install DHCP, BIND, Sendmail, SpamAssassin, MailScanner, Dovecot, Squirrelmail on the new server.
3. Transfer  settings  from the old server to the new server. ( This is the hardest part that we know). For DHCP and DNS, we can just copy the dhcp leases and conf file and everything should work right?

How do we go about moving the users/email accounts from the old server to the new one?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Moving the user accounts and data will depend on your authentication database and data format. I will assume that you are using actual *nix accounts for sendmail (as opposed to storing accounts/mailboxes in a database), as this is the default.

You need only create new accounts with the same usernames on the new system to create the mailboxes. Don't forget to copy over /etc/aliases as well. You need to determine what format your new system will store email in (i.e. MH, mbox, Maildirs, etc.) and transform the stored messages from the old system to the new format (assuming the format has changed). There are numerous scripts available online to handle these things. Make sure when you copy messages to the new system that you check the user and group ownership and file permissions. Your user's UIDs on the new system might not be the same as on the old system.